# Jenkins FreeStyle Project From GitHub give "fatal: not in a git directory" error

Tags: github, jenkins

I've been trying for three days now to find a solution, but without success. Pipeline type is working succesfully, freestyle don't working.
I noticed that after every attempt, in the HEAD file .git  written "ref: refs/heads/master", even I indicated */main.

[image]

```
Running as SYSTEM
    Building in workspace C:\Users\aziz\.jenkins\workspace\workflow
    The recommended git tool is: NONE
    using credential 605f1b8b-aff7-457a-8040-edf8d6dae69a
     > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Users\aziz\.jenkins\workspace\workflow\.git # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/azimkar87/Billing.git # timeout=10
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/azimkar87/Billing.git
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1003)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1244)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1308)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1217)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:647)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:519)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1897)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/azimkar87/Billing.git" returned status code 128:
    stdout: 
    stderr: fatal: not in a git directory
    
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2601)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2597)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1968)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1980)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.setRemoteUrl(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1594)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.setRemoteUrl(GitAPI.java:161)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:991)
        ... 11 more
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
    [Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you try removing the .git extension from the repository url (ttps://github.com/azimkar87/Billing)

Answer (score 5):

1. Check if the ssh key is added.
2. Execute following commands,

> cd /var/jenkins_home
> git config --global --add safe.directory '*'

4. Delete workspace using option "Delete workspace before build starts"
5. Run Jenkins job

Answer (score 4):

The root cause is **corrupted cache**. I had same issue here's what I did:

```
su - jenkins
cd /var/jenkins_home
mv caches/ caches2
```

Running pipeline again.

Reference: [Branch Indexing fails with 'Could not fetch branches from source' error](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/branch-indexing-fails-with-could-not-fetch-branches-from-source)

Comment: This solved the problem for us as well, having upgraded from 2.4.5 to 2.875 TLS. Thank you and have an up-vote!

Comment: Same here. I gave 2.387.2 (2.875 do not exist).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you face the problem described here ( https://community.jenkins.io/t/upgrading-git-on-jenkins-master-causing-failures-for-multibranch-pipelines/3247 ) and upgrading git would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash at the end of the git repository url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will work well. But it's best to use Rafael's solution to avoid replacing git URLs in all jobs.